# Batch clipping all files in folder and then save using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, clip, batch, iteration

I'm trying to use a script to batch clip all files in a folder, then saved with a _clipped.shp at the end of the original, I need a script that is something like this:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "E:\\folder\\test_input"

# Set local variables
in_features = arcpy.env.workspace
clip_features = "E:\\folder\\mask\\boundary.shp"
out_feature_class = "_clipped.shp"
 
# Execute Clip
for f in arcpy.env.workspace
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(f, clip_features, f(name) + out_feature_class)
```

Where the f(name) 'points' to the orignal shapefile name and then 'appends' _clipped.shp at the end and then saves and performs this process iteratively for each file.

Also should I have a different output folder for the clipped features?

The reason I'm doing this is because the actual batch clip feature of the clip tool is not working for some reason.

Comment: You need to use ListFeatureClasses to get a handle of the datasets in a folder, see the help file for correct usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\GIS\data\testdata\clip' #Your folder with the shapefiles to be clipped
outfolder = r'C:\GIS\data\testdata\clipout'
cutter = r'C:\GIS\data\testdata\clippolygon.shp'

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(): #List shapes in workspace
    print 'Clipping: ', fc
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(in_features=fc, clip_features=cutter, out_feature_class=os.path.join(outfolder, fc.replace('.shp','_clipped.shp')))
```

[image]